# Who was the last prime minister never to have been elected at all

Tags: united-kingdom

Who was the last prime minister of the UK never to have been elected to the House of Commons. I believe Robert Gascoyne-Cecil, 3rd Marquess of Salisbury  was prime minister while a member of the House of Lords. However he was elected to the House of Commons previously in 1854.

I am interested in the last prime minister never to have been elected to the House of Commons at all.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first prime minister to be elected directly from the House of Lords was [Spencer Compton, 1st Earl of Wilmington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_Compton,_1st_Earl_of_Wilmington) and the last was either:

- [Robert Gascoyne-Cecil, 3rd Marquess of Salisbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Gascoyne-Cecil,_3rd_Marquess_of_Salisbury) who was the last Prime Minister from the House of Lords

or

- [Archibald Primrose, 5th Earl of Rosebery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archibald_Primrose,_5th_Earl_of_Rosebery) who wasn't entitles to sit in the House of Lords as his earldom was part of the [Old Peerage of Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peerage_of_Scotland)
  however, he inherited from his grandfather the Barony of Rosebery which did entitle him to sit in the House of Lords, and crucially, **barred him from sitting in the House of Commons**

Resources:
[Wikipedia: List of Prime Ministers of The United Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Prime_Ministers_of_the_United_Kingdom)

Comment: Gascoyne-Cecil, 3rd Marquess of Salisbury was in my question as someone who had been elected previously so isn't relevant.  Maybe Archibald Primrose is the answer.